# How to index data using edge ngram in elasticsearch which include spaces also?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am using the edge ngram analyzer. While checking the analyze API for the field I am getting the below result.

For example for the query "galaxy j7", it is analyzed as.

```
["g","ga","gal","gala","galax","galaxy","j","j7"]
```

I want data to be analyzed as below.

```
["g","ga","gal","gala","galax","galaxy","galaxy j","galaxy j7"]
```

How can this possible?

The setting in index is as follows .

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "20"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_analyzer": {
            "filter": ["lowercase", "autocomplete_filter"],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and mapping of field is below.

```
{
    "title_suggest": {
        "type": "string",
        "index_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "search_quote_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [edgeNGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html), instead of an edge_ngram filter:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete_tokenizer": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "20"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_analyzer": {
            "filter": ["lowercase"],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this also. But no use.

Comment: What didn't work? You need to delete your index, recreate it with the new analyzer and then reindex your data. How did you proceed?

Comment: I did by that only .But still getting the same as result . Like ["g","ga","gal","gala","galax","galaxy","j","j7"]
But wanted the other one. It is only spliting by words.I need it by whole sentence.

Comment: I sincerely doubt it. Are you sure you don't have a `standard` tokenizer instead? Also make sure to remove the `autocomplete_filter` from the filter list

Comment: Please check the below link.  Is there any way to achieve the below . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182538/word-ngrams-in-elasticsearch-of-exact-order